# Unable access to opportunity object fields in apex classes and trigger?

Tags: apex

[image] Unable to access opportunity object fields in apex classes and in triggers also .even in the standard way of creating apex classes. getting an error as variable doesn't Exist, even field is available.
please help me out on this

Comment: In the future, you should upload your code as text instead of a screenshot. It's easier to copy into an answer & easier to read.

Comment: @battery.cord yaa sure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens when your organization has a class named as `Opportunity`.

Check in your list of classes which is named as `Opportunity` and rename it to something else.

Compiler searches for `Amount` property in your custom made `Opportunity` class which if doesn't exist, then it gives an compilation error.

Compile all your classes post renaming and then try saving your changes.

You can compile all classes by navigating from Setup > Develop > Apex Classes > Click on Compile all classes

**Note :** You should never create classes with the names which are already being used by the platform.

Comment: even after renaming the class unable to access fields

Comment: Compile all your classes post renaming and then try saving your trigger changes. You can compile all classes by navigating from Setup > Develop > Apex Classes > Click on Compile all classes